# Is there a way to render an image saved with an activex control in the browser, without sending it to the server?

Tags: c#, file-upload, activex

I have an **html** page that allows users to click on a link to take a **snapshot of any active window**. When the user clicks on that button, control is passed to `C# code of an ActiveX` plugin (present in a **CAB** file), which takes the screenshot, and saves it at some temporary location. My problems are :

1. I wish to **show the user that snapshot in a dialog box**, and ask him to choose a name before sending it to the server. The snapshot is saved in a temporary location, and that location is obviously not accessible to the **javascript** code, and hence I can't construct the dialog box in HTML. Is there any way around it ?
2. I have to upload the image to the server. Most examples I found, use the `<html type="file"/>` technique to upload a file, but that's not an option here, as we have to programmatically upload it. `WebClient.uploadFile()` would do this for me, but on the server side, do I treat it as if the file has been uploaded through the `<html type="file"/`> technique, or something special (the receiving end might be in Java) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to modify the activex component, you can make it expose the bitmap as a binary and use javascript to get the bytes and render them as a bitmap. Like this:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
        var excelApp = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application");
        excelApp.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert (e.message);
    }
}
else {
    alert ("Your browser does not support this example.");
}
```

Comment: In order to expose the image object that I am getting inside the activeX element as a binary, we need to save it as a binary at some location, for javascript to access it, but as far as I know, javascript can't access files on the local filesystem. Where should I save it so that js can access it ?

Comment: Nope. You can make your Activex object to expose a property and access that property from javascript.

Comment: Thanks for that. I assume that if we have set a property 'image' to the binary equivalent of the image in the activeX class, we will do 

var imageBytes = excelApp.image;
image.src="data:image/png;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)

But I can't find any straight way to convert an image object to a byte